# Override get_shipping() for "Cartthrob shipping by location price threshold" plugin

Tags: cartthrob

I am using `Cartthrob_shipping_by_location_price_threshold` plugin for `Cartthrob`.

What I need is to have a shipping by location price but, sometime I have software products, and this software products has shipping tax 0.

There is a function get_shipping() in the `Cartthrob_shipping_by_location_price_threshold` class:

```
public function get_shipping()
{
    $location = '';
    $customer_info = $this->core->cart->customer_info();

    $location_field = $this->plugin_settings('location_field', 'shipping_country_code');
    $backup_location_field = $this->plugin_settings('backup_location_field', 'country_code');
    ........................
 }
```

And I would like to override this function. One other thing, how can I access a product shipping price? As I see the shipping price field was added from Channel Administration -> Field Editor

```
    foreach ($this->core->cart->items() as $item)
    {
        print_r($item->..........shipping_price_field?.....);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I'm with Vector, the people behind CartThrob)

Instead of overriding this, you should just create your own shipping plugin. You can duplicate `Cartthrob_shipping_by_location_price_threshold` in its folder, rename it, and update the class names/friendly name. Then you can implement any logic changes to `get_shipping()` you'd like.

For item price, are you looking for this?

```
foreach ($this->order('items') as $row_id => $item) {
    $price = $item['price'];
}
```